# How to unit test functions which call other non-virtual functions?

Tags: unit-testing

I have several functions to unit test

```
public class MyClass {

   public DataObj  FuncX  (int input1, int input2) {

       if( input1 < 0 && input2 > 0 ){
           return Func01();
       }
       else if(input1 < 2 && input2 < 0) {
           return Func02();
       }
       ....
       return Func0N();
   }
}
```

I already have many unit tests for functions like `Func01()`, `Func02()`, but I don't know how to unit test `FuncX()`.

(Note: `Func01()` and other functions are not virtual)

Comment: you could ***make*** your functions virtual.  Then in funcX, test that the appropriate mocked/virtual function was invoked based on the logic on why one would be invoked over another.

Answer (score 0):

Just like testing [private methods](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/100966), you can't actually test functions inside a method. You should expect to have result X from a function Y no matter what things are happening inside of it.

There is an unspoken contract between the function you are testing and the functions that it's calling that is ensuring everything should work as expected. If internal function don't work as it's supposed to be, the external one won't work either, but the reason of test failure should not be the concern of your test in that case.

Create tests for internal functions and then for the one that's calling them, this way you'll be able to find the cause of test failure easily.

Comment: My functions are all public(but not virtual).

Comment: Test all of them. It's impossible to test virtual functions anyway (as they are virtual, so you can't really call them, only when they are overridden), test concrete functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to suggest the following options:

- Do a 'full' test of `FuncX`, including the test of the functions called - This is undesirable because you have already tested `Func01` etc., and a full test of `FuncX` would then duplicate all these tests.
- Do an isolated test of `FuncX`, by (somehow) using doubles for the called functions `Func01` etc.  This is difficult, because the called functions are not virtual.

There is, however, another option: When unit-testing a function with dependencies, you only have to do something about a dependency if it causes you trouble.  If it doesn't cause trouble, you just can live with the dependency.  For example, if some code depends on the programming language's mathematical library (for example the `sin()` function), this is also a dependency - but this dependency is almost never replaced by doubles.

Good reasons to use doubles are if the dependencies cause non-deterministic behaviour, take long to compute, are buggy or not implemented yet or make certain test scenarios hard to perform - to name some important ones.

But, if your dependencies do not cause any trouble - just perform the unit tests with them.  In your example, just live with the fact that `FuncX` calls `Func01` etc.  As long as you can from the results easily determine whether `FuncX` has worked properly (i.e. which decision `FuncX` has taken), you can test `FuncX` as well as if you had doubled `Func01` and the others.